# Can I use Multiply Nameservers

Tags: dns, host, nameservers

I have a domain and the host (Education Host) require to change the nameserver of that domain to its nameservers but the host doesn't have a DNS zone so I want to manage DNS with CloudFlare but its require to change nameservers too. So I want to use both of them but I don't know what happens?

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You should try to post at Server Fault. Can you clarify with more information with examples? Your description is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens, enter to your Cloudflare panel, change your domains DNS to Cloudflare DNS and in the IP section; Insert IP of your hosts (Education Host).
This will connect your domain to the host, and you can also manage domain records in Cloudfler.
reading [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019093151-Managing-DNS-records-in-Cloudflare) article will help you.